# Create TreeView with different child object in every node with full respect of WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I want to create treeView as following with full respect of Wpf MVVM:

> Root   //Level 0
>
> B1- Child1  // Level 1
>
> B1-1- Child1-1  //  Level 2
>
> B1-2- Child1-2
>
> B1-3- ...
>
> B2- Child2   // Level1
>
> B2-1 Child2-1 // Level 2
>
> B2-2 Child2-2
>
> B2-3 ...

As you can see, I have TreeView with 3 Level.

Level 0: Root (Always Fix)

Level 1: Two child (Always Fix too)

Level 2: Dynamic Child and they are created from two different class

So **My question** is how Can I create different child in Level 2 for every node in Level 1.

I used the code below but I have always the same children under parents in Level 1.

I have looked at many of the solution proposed on this site as well as on the web... but just cant figure out how to do it...

My attempt:

```
  public class MyViewModel 
{
    //private ReadOnlyCollection<AttributesMapDocViewModel> _attributeMapDoc;

    public object _document;

    #region Methodes




    private List<Level0ViewModel> _myDoc;

    public List<Level0ViewModel> MyDoc
    {
        get { return _myDoc; }
        set
        {
            _myDoc = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructeur

    public MyViewModel()
    {


        MyDoc = new List<Level0ViewModel>()
        {
            new Level0ViewModel("Root",_document), //_document conatins data from xml file (code not shown)
        };
    }


    #endregion

}

public class Level0ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<Level1ViewModel> _childLevel1;

    public Level0ViewModel(string name, object myObj)
    {
        ChildLeve0Name = name;
        ChildLevel1 = new List<Level1ViewModel>()
        {
            new Level1ViewModel("Child1",myObj),
            new Level1ViewModel("Child2",myObj)
        };
    }

    public List<Level1ViewModel> ChildLevel1
    {
        get
        {
            return _childLevel1;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _childLevel1, value, () => ChildLevel1);

        }
    }

    public string ChildLeve0Name { get; set; }
}

public class Level1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Level2SecondTypeViewModel> _childLevel2SecondType;
    public ObservableCollection<Level2SecondTypeViewModel> ChildLevel2SecondType
    {
        get { return _childLevel2SecondType; }
        set
        {
            if (_childLevel2SecondType != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _childLevel2SecondType, value, () => ChildLevel2SecondType);

            }
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Level2FirstTypeViewModel> _childLevel2FirstType;
    public ObservableCollection<Level2FirstTypeViewModel> ChildLevel2FirstType
    {
        get { return _childLevel2FirstType; }
        set
        {
            if (_childLevel2FirstType != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _childLevel2FirstType, value, () => ChildLevel2FirstType);

            }
        }
    }

    public Level1ViewModel(string name, object mapAtt)
    {
        ChildLevel1Name = name;

        ChildLevel2FirstType = new ObservableCollection<Level2FirstTypeViewModel>();
        foreach (FirstType myFirstType in mapAtt.FirstTypes)
        {
            ChildLevel2FirstType.Add(new Level2FirstTypeViewModel(myFirstType));
        }

        ChildLevel2SecondType = new ObservableCollection<Level2SecondTypeViewModel>();
        foreach (SecondType mySecondType in mapAtt.SecondTypes)
        {
            ChildLevel2SecondType.Add(new Level2SecondTypeViewModel(mySecondType));
        }

    }

    public string ChildLevel1Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Level2FirstTypeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Level2FirstTypeViewModel(FirstType fType)
    {
        FirstTypeName = fType.name;
    }

    public string FirstTypeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class Level2SecondTypeViewModel
{
    public Level2SecondTypeViewModel(SecondType sType)
    {
        SecondTypeName = sType.name;
    }

    public string SecondTypeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}




 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyDoc}" >
  <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MapAttDef}" DataType="{x:Type local:Level0ViewModel}">
                      <Label Content="{Binding ChildLeve0Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildLevel2SecondType}" DataType="{x:Type local:Level1ViewModel}">
                      <Label Content="{Binding ChildLevel1Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Level2SecondTypeViewModel}">
                       <Label Content="{Binding FirstTypeName}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Level2FirstTypeViewModel}">
                        <Label Content="{Binding SecondTypeName}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>




   </TreeView.Resources>
```

My Attempt give me something like this ( that isn't what I want at all !!):

> > Root   //Level 0
>
> B1- Child1  // Level 1
>
> B1-1- Child1-1  //  Level 2
>
> B1-2- Child1-2
>
> B1-3- ...
>
> B2- Child2   // Level1
>
> B2-1 Child1-1 // Level 2
>
> B2-2 Child1-2
>
> B2-3 ...

Answer (score 0):

Throw away these properties: `Level1ViewModel.ChildLevel2FirstType` and `Level1ViewModel.ChildLevel2SecondType`.

You need single collection for children. The item type of this collection depends on inheritance hierarchy and should be nearest common ancestor (worst case is `object`), that is, like this:

```
public Level1ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> ChildLevel2
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Markup with these changes will look like this:

```
    <!-- Level 1 -->
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Level1ViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildLevel2}">
              <Label Content="{Binding ChildLevel1Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!-- Level 1 -->
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Level2FirstTypeViewModel}">
                <Label Content="{Binding SecondTypeName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Level2SecondTypeViewModel}">
               <Label Content="{Binding FirstTypeName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Note, that `HierarchicalDataTemplate` must be used for *hierarchical* data sources only. For non-hierarchical ones (like `Level2FirstTypeViewModel` and 
`Level2SecondTypeViewModel`) use regular `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but can you be more explicit by giving us an exemple ( treeview with Company - departement - employee for exemple ). Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseTreeViewItem<TSource, TParent> : ViewModelBase
{

    // add static field to hold selected Item
    public static BaseTreeViewItem<TSource, TParent> SelectedChild { get; set; }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected == value) return;

            if (SelectedChild != null)
            {
                SelectedChild.IsSelected = false;
                SelectedChild = null;
            }

            _isSelected = value;

            if (_isSelected)
                SelectedChild = this;

            // NotifyPropertyChanged
        }
    }

    public TParent Parent
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public BaseTreeViewItem(string name, TSource myObj, TParent parent)
    {
        ChildName = name;
        DataSource = myObj;
        Parent = parent;
    }


    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public TSource DataSource { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ChildName;
    }
}

// Node

public class MyTreeViewItem<TChild, TSource, TParent> : BaseTreeViewItem<TSource, TParent>, IDeleteItem
    where TParent : IDeleteItem
    where TChild : class
{


    public ObservableCollection<TChild> Children { get; set; }

    public MyTreeViewItem(string name, TSource myObj, TParent parent)
        :base(name,myObj, parent)
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<TChild>();
    }

    protected virtual void InitChild()
    {

    }

    public void DeleteItem(object myTreeViewItem)
    {
        Children.Remove(myTreeViewItem as TChild);
    }

    public static void DeleteSelectedItem()
    {
        if (SelectedChild != null && SelectedChild.Parent != null)
        {
            SelectedChild.Parent.DeleteItem(SelectedChild);
        }
    }


}

public class Level0ViewModel : MyTreeViewItem<Level1ViewModel, XmlDocument, IDeleteItem>
{
    protected override sealed void InitChild()
    {
        base.InitChild();
        Children.Add(new Level1ViewModel("Child1", new Level1Src(), this));
        Children.Add(new Level1ViewModel("Child2", new Level1Src(), this));
    }

    public Level0ViewModel(string name, XmlDocument myObj) :
        base(name, myObj,null)
    {
        InitChild();
    }
}

public class Level1ViewModel : MyTreeViewItem<Level2TypeViewModel, Level1Src, Level0ViewModel>
{
    public Level1ViewModel(string name, Level1Src myObj, Level0ViewModel parent)
        : base(name, myObj, parent)
    {
        InitChild();
    }

    protected override sealed void InitChild()
    {
        base.InitChild();
        foreach (FirstType myFirstType in DataSource.FirstTypes)
        {
            Children.Add(new Level2TypeViewModel(myFirstType, this));
        }

        foreach (SecondType mySecondType in DataSource.SecondTypes)
        {
            Children.Add(new Level2TypeViewModel(mySecondType, this));
        }
    }

    // Use linq if tou want child by type
    public IEnumerable<Level2TypeViewModel> ChildType1 
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.Where(item => item.DataSource is FirstType);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Level2TypeViewModel> ChildType2
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.Where(item => item.DataSource is SecondType);
        }
    }
}

public class LevelType
{
    public string Name;
}

public class FirstType : LevelType
{
}

public class SecondType : LevelType
{
}

public class Level2TypeViewModel : BaseTreeViewItem<LevelType, Level1ViewModel>
{
    public Level2TypeViewModel(LevelType sType, Level1ViewModel parent)
        : base(sType.Name, sType, parent)
    {
    }
}
```

My Data Source is

```
public Level0ViewModel TreeModel
    {
        get
        {
            return new Level0ViewModel("Root", new XmlDocument());
        }
    }
```

For TreeView DataTemplate use

```
<TreeView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=TreeModel}">
        <TreeView.Items>
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding ChildName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" >
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <Label Content="{Binding ChildName}"></Label>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView.Items>

    </TreeView>
```

The First treeviewItem is to show root node. if you do not want to use it
You can change data source to

```
public MyTreeViewItem<Level0ViewModel,object> TreeModel
        {
            get
            {
                MyTreeViewItem<Level0ViewModel,object> src = new MyTreeViewItem<Level0ViewModel, object>("Root", null);
                src.Children.Add(new Level0ViewModel("toto", new XmlDocument()));
                return src;
            }
        }
```

And DataTemplate to

```
<TreeView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=TreeModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                            <Label Content="{Binding ChildName}"></Label>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
 </TreeView>
```

**sample way**

```
public class TreeViewItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    // add static field to hold selected Item
    public static TreeViewItemViewModel SelectedChild { get; set; }
    public TreeViewItemViewModel Parent{ get; private set;}
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public object DataSource { get; set; }
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> _children;

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }

    }


    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected == value) return;

            if (SelectedChild != null)
            {
                SelectedChild.IsSelected = false;
                SelectedChild = null;
            }

            _isSelected = value;

            if (_isSelected)
                SelectedChild = this;

            // NotifyPropertyChanged
        }
    }


    public TreeViewItemViewModel(string name, object myObj, TreeViewItemViewModel parent)
    {
        ChildName = name;
        DataSource = myObj;
        Parent = parent;
        _children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ChildName;
    }


    protected virtual void InitChild()
    {

    }

    public void DeleteItem(TreeViewItemViewModel myTreeViewItem)
    {
        Children.Remove(myTreeViewItem);
    }

    public static void DeleteSelectedItem()
    {
        if (SelectedChild != null && SelectedChild.Parent != null)
        {
            SelectedChild.Parent.DeleteItem(SelectedChild);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use ItemTemplateSelector if u want different style depends on Type

Comment: thank you for your fast answer, you are using the approach describe in this article " http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode".

I already use it and I succeed to develop my treeview as I want but then I couldn't find any solution to remove selected item. so after many attempt I decided to change the approach that I used to create my treeview.

Comment: I guess thee added "Selected Child" or "IsSelected" In ViewModel ? what's the exact problem to remove selectedItem ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what do you mean. I know that I have "IsSelected" but not "Selected Child". BTW can you edit you answer and describe for us a situation how to delete selected child from treeview ! Hope that where are always talking about the same article " http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode"

Comment: you can delete generic information to simplify the code

Answer (score 0):

If u have one selected Item in your view model u can use this approach

public class TreeViewItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

```
    // add static field to hold selected Item
    public static TreeViewItemViewModel SelectedChild { get; set; }
    public TreeViewItemViewModel Parent{ get; private set;}
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public object DataSource { get; set; }
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> _children;

    public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }

    }


    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected == value) return;

            if (SelectedChild != null)
            {
                SelectedChild.IsSelected = false;
                SelectedChild = null;
            }

            _isSelected = value;

            if (_isSelected)
                SelectedChild = this;

            // NotifyPropertyChanged
        }
    }


    public TreeViewItemViewModel(string name, object myObj, TreeViewItemViewModel parent)
    {
        ChildName = name;
        DataSource = myObj;
        Parent = parent;
        _children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ChildName;
    }


    protected virtual void InitChild()
    {

    }

    public void DeleteItem(TreeViewItemViewModel myTreeViewItem)
    {
        Children.Remove(myTreeViewItem);
    }

    public static void DeleteSelectedItem()
    {
        if (SelectedChild != null && SelectedChild.Parent != null)
        {
            SelectedChild.Parent.DeleteItem(SelectedChild);
        }
    }
}
```